# Getting Exception CryptoException.ILLEGAL value when using HMACKey.setkey

Tags: javacard, hmacsha1

I want to Generate HMAC_SHA1 Signature in JavaCard Applet

I am trying to sign a message which contains in inBuffer byte array  S (byte array , 64 byte). The snippet of the function from javacard (jc) applet module is given below. I am using javacard3.0.1 library for developing jc applet.

```
 Signature m_sessionMAC = null;
 HMACKey keyType = null;


 // Create HMAC Key Used in Mac
 m_sessionMAC = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_HMAC_SHA_1, false);

// Create HMAC Key Used in Mac
keyType = (HMACKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_HMAC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_HMAC_SHA_256_BLOCK_64, false); 
keyType.setKey(S,(short) 0, (short) S.length);
```

this keyType.setKey result in exception as ILLEGAL_VALUE, please guide me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key length is specified in bits -- citing [KeyBuilder.buildKey() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/KeyBuilder.html#buildKey(byte,%20short,%20boolean)):

> keyLength - the **key size in bits**. The valid key bit lengths are key type dependent. Some common key lengths are listed above in the LENGTH_* constants, for example LENGTH_DES.

Which means:

- use `512` for a 64 byte key
- use `64` for a 8 byte key

Note that you can use any key length for HMAC-SHA1, but keys longer than block size (which is 64 bytes for SHA-1) are transformed into their SHA-1 hash before use (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Definition)).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't notice its size in bits.